# hover two objects affecting on one object

Tags: css, hover, effects

i have a problem of making two objects that when i hover on one of them, it will change one object. for example, i have object bar1, bar2, and bar3. i want to make when i hover on bar1 or bar3 will change the bar2.this is the css code:

```
.bar2{
   left:0.5%;
   right:0.5%;
}
.bar1:hover + .bar2{left:5%;}
.bar3:hover + .bar2{right:5%;}
```

and this is my html code:

```
<div style="position:absolute;">
    <div class="bar1">
    </div>
    <div class="bar2">
    </div>
    <div class="bar3">
    </div>
</div>
```

from that code i just can affect bar2 by hovering on bar1, but not with bar3.
Every body please help me. and thanks for helping.

Comment: You should always try to include a demo on jsbin.com or something similar, PLEASE format your css in a readable manner, and you don't need to include all of the css that isn't directly relevant to your issue. You're making it that much more difficult for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is something like this: [live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/UVeQAZoW/1/edit)

```
<div class="bar1">Bar 1
</div>
<div class="bar3">Bar 3
</div>
<div class="bar2">Bar 2
</div>
```

css:

```
#one {
  background: red;
}
#two {
  background: white;
}
#three {
  background: blue;
}

#one:hover ~ #two, #three:hover ~ #two {
  background: black;
}
```

`.bar3:hover + .bar2` or `.bar3:hover ~ .bar2` is only going to select `.bar2` if `.bar2` is **AFTER** `.bar3`.

It might make more semantic sense for the elements to be in a different order, but in a lot of cases (such as yours here), the result is visually the same even with the order changed. If you can't change the order in order to select things this way, then you would have to resort to javascript to select adjacent elements that are previous.

There is talk of having a parent selector in css4. That would be nice :)